# How to disable row selection of jqgrid upon left click of mouse

Tags: jqgrid, selection, rows

I am using jqgrid in my ASP.net MVC 2.0 application. In my grid , i dont need to select any of the rows . So, i disabled it using the following piece of code:

```
  beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {return false;}
```

This is stopping the row selection event to be fired , when clicked on it using mouse left click.

But, the problem here is , it is not stopping on right click. The color of the row is changing indicating the row selection

how to stop this? Plese help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of such behaiver is in [the part](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.4/js/grid.base.js#L2731-L2740) of jqGrid code which process right mouse click. The most simple way to fix the problem would by unbinding of `contextmenu` event:

```js
$("#grid").unbind("contextmenu");
```